# win32api: temporarily block mouse clicks?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32

Is there any way to disable regular windows mouse clicks using the win API? I can disable clicks anywhere besides a particular point by doing `ClipCursor`, but the clicks still register.

Alternatively I also want to disable mouse clicks conditionally... for example, I want to make it impossible to close a window of an application I don't control, so I want clicks sent to the 'X' of that window to not go through.

Comment: There is a good reason this is difficult to do. You should not do this at all. For whatever you are trying to solve, try a better solution. Even the idea of "preventing closing an app" is so bad-bear. You will just encourage killing the app via task manager. What about ALT+F4, or ALT+f,x?

Comment: @tenfour: i only want to prevent accidental closing of the window with 'X' button.

Comment: Then register an event handler and put up a dialog box asking for confirmation. Do _not_ prevent the user from closing the window if they really want to.

Comment: This question and your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080777) would both be much improved if you would explain what you are actually trying to do. I've already asked you, why can't you tell us? Or if you simply won't why don't you state that.

Comment: @David: the scenario is a person is sitting at the computer, using App X, which requires lots of mouse clicking. my program is interfacing with App Y running on the same computer, and to interface it it has to do things like type things to it uninterrupted. this has to work while the user is sitting there & clicking on App X. i dont' have the code to App Y so I can't do it neatly with API calls or whatnot.

Answer (score 3):

You can, and it's very dangerous. Here's how, in c++

```
LRESULT __stdcall LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nCode < 0) || false)
    {
        result = CallNextHookEx(myLowLevelMouseHookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Change the `false` in the example above to re-enable keyboard to work.

BTW this technique also works similarly with keyboard input, even Ctrl+Alt+Del wont work.

If you want to allow the mouse to move, but block clicks only, add some `if ((wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE) || (wParam == WM_NCMOUSEMOVE))` code.

More info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644986(VS.85).aspx

Comment: i assume i have to `sethookex` or something so the OS does something with that function?

Comment: Correct:  myLowLevelMouseHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, &LowLevelMouseProc, myInstance, 0);
 myLowLevelMouseHookInstalled = (myLowLevelMouseHookHandle != NULL);