# win32gui.FindWindow Not finding window

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32, teraterm

I'm trying to send a keystroke to an inactive TeraTerm Window using Pywin32.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38888131/3714940) answer led me to write this code:

```
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api

hwndMain = win32gui.FindWindow("Tera Term VT", None)
print hwndMain
hwndChild = win32gui.GetWindow(hwndMain, win32con.GW_CHILD)
win32api.PostMessage(hwndChild, win32con.WM_CHAR, 0x5b, 0)
```

but:
`hwndMain = win32gui.FindWindow("Tera Term VT", None)` returns `0`, it can't find the window.

If I change `"Tera Term VT"` to `"Notepad"`, I can happily send keystrokes to an active Notepad window all day long. So, why can't I  get the TeraTerm window?

According to the [ActiveState documentation](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32gui__FindWindow_meth.html):

> PyHANDLE = FindWindow(ClassName, WindowName)
>
> ClassName : PyResourceId
>   Name or atom of window class to find, can be None
>   WindowName : string
>   Title of window to find, can be None

So how can I get the correct ClassName to use?

I've tried just about every variation of `Tera Term VT`, escaping the spaces: `"Tera\ Term\ VT"`, enclosing the whole in single quotes: `"'Tera Term VT'"`, but nothing works. I've even tried using the name of the process:`"ttermpro.exe"`, and included the child name in the string `"COM11:115200baud - Tera Term VT"` in my desperation, but nothing works.

Interestingly,  this:

```
import win32com.client

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.AppActivate("Tera Term VT")
shell.SendKeys("\%i", 0)
```

works just fine, but brings the window to the foreground, which I don't wan't. The `Tera Term VT` string works fine in this instance though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The line

```
shell.AppActivate("Tera Term VT")
```

works on the window title and therefore it works.
You should be able to to the same with

```
hwndMain = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Tera Term VT")
```

that is, swapping the arguments so that it also works based on the window title

If you want to work based on the window class name you could use a tool like Spy++ with its [Finder Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460750.aspx) to target the Tera Term window and get its window class name from the properties

Comment: Alas, swapping the arguments does not help. I will investigate the Finder Tool. though. Thanks.

Comment: Then the title did not match exactly with "Tera Term VT" at that time I guess - maybe you can provide a screenshot of the window. Nevertheless, a solution based on the window class name is better anyway as the application may change the title at any time.

Comment: Thanks, I've learnt something today; Window Classes are new to me! Downloaded [WinSpy++](http://www.pendriveapps.com/winspy-find-window-properties/), and found that the Class is, in fact `VTWin32`, and this works perfectly.