# The program not reacting to the message I sent with win32api in Python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32

everyone.

I was trying to learn winapi/pywin32, by remotely controlling some programs. So I decided to try something different and chose [The Powder Toy](https://powdertoy.co.uk/) to test. Then I took [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996985/send-some-keys-to-inactive-window-with-python/38888131#38888131) as an example and wrote this (Also used Spy++ to determine some parameters):

```
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api
from time import sleep

hwndMain = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "The Powder Toy")

while True:
    win32api.PostMessage(hwndMain, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, 0x44, 2097153)
    win32api.PostMessage(hwndMain, win32con.WM_KEYUP, 0x44, 0)
    sleep(1)
```

It takes HWND, as it supposed to be, also sends a similar message to The Powder Toy's window, but it's not reacting for some reason. For example:

When I press "d":

```
...WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'D'cRepeat:1 ScanCode:20fExtended:0fAltDown:0fRepeat:0fUp:0
...WM_CHAR chCharCode:'100'(100)cRepeat:1 ScanCode:20fExtended:0fAltDown:0fRepeat:0fUp:0
...WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:'D'cRepeat:1 ScanCode:20fExtended:0fAltDown:0fRepeat:1fUp:1
```

When I try to send "d":

```
...WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'D'cRepeat:1 ScanCode:20fExtended:0fAltDown:0fRepeat:0fUp:0
...WM_CHAR chCharCode:'100'(100)cRepeat:1 ScanCode:20fExtended:0fAltDown:1fRepeat:0fUp:0
...WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:'D'cRepeat:1 ScanCode:00fExtended:0fAltDown:1fRepeat:0fUp:0
...WM_CHAR chCharCode:'100'(100)cRepeat:1 ScanCode:00fExtended:0fAltDown:1fRepeat:0fUp:0
```

Can someone explain why it's not working, and if it's possible, how to fix it?

Comment: Stop asking the same question all over again. [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: Thank you for your kind words, @IInspectable. I used PostMessage, because in that situation, both SendMessage and PostMessage had the same problem, same way. The problem was at the lParameter of them. It looks like I posted the wrong part of the code there, with right lParameters :) I have called win32con.WM_KEYUP with lParameter 0 on my original code, which caused some problems. Still, thank you. Your comment made me look at my code more carefully. I wouldn't be noticed the problem and the importance of lParameters without your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had to give the ScanCode to lParameters for WM_KEYUP, along with 0x44, to make The Powder Toy work.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.