# Use pyautogui to control an application in background

Tags: python, pyautogui, python-tesseract

Disclaimer- I am new to coding and just started learning not long ago so don't judge me for the code, thanks.

I made a bot for my game to do some particular tasks but problem is that it uses pyautogui and pytessarect but in order to run the program the game should be on the screen means i can't do anything on the system if i need that program to run.

So I was wondering is there any way to run the code with game in the background so i can use my system in the meantime

Here is the code

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.FAILSAFE=False

import time

import keyboard

from pyautogui import *



import pytesseract as tess

from pygame.event import get_grab

tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\arshi_k8rjg1x\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab

a = input("Name of pokemon:")

name="VS. "+"Wild "+a+'\n'

b = input("Name of pokemon:")

name1="VS. "+"Wild "+b+'\n'

c = input("Name of pokemon:")

name2="VS. "+"Wild "+c+'\n'

time.sleep(3)




def movement():
    while pyautogui.pixel(1248, 496)[0] != 27 and [1] != 25 and [2] != 27:

        pyautogui.keyDown('D')

        time.sleep(0.05)
        pyautogui.keyUp('D')

        time.sleep(0.05)
        pyautogui.keyDown('A')
        time.sleep(0.05)
        pyautogui.keyUp('A')

    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(831, 320, 1100, 350))
    text = tess.image_to_string(img)
    

    if text == name or text==name1 or text==name2:
        time.sleep(6)
        attack()

    else:
        pyautogui.keyDown('4')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.keyUp('4')
        time.sleep(2)
        movement()



def attack():

    pyautogui.keyDown('1')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    pyautogui.keyUp('1')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    pyautogui.keyDown('3')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    pyautogui.keyUp('3')
    time.sleep(9)
    pyautogui.keyDown('3')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    pyautogui.keyUp('3')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    pyautogui.keyDown('1')
    pyautogui.keyUp('1')



    movement()
movement()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyautogui simulates actual input to the system. For example when you run `pyautogui.press('enter')` it is the same as if you manually pressed `Enter` on you keyboard. For that reason, pyautogui cannot play a game in the background, as it sends the input to the system itself and not a specific window. If you wanted to send input to a specific window while still keeping it in the background, the process would be much more complicated. You can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996985/send-some-keys-to-inactive-window-with-python) about that.