# Emulating a mouseclick using PostMessage

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I am using python's win32 module to create a simple click() method, which should emulate a mouse click, but unfortunately my approach is not working.

```
def click(x, y):
    hWnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "SomeWindowTitle")
    lParam = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)

    win32gui.PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, lParam);
    win32gui.PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, lParam);

...
timer = Timer(30, click, [x, y])
timer.start()
```

I am thankful for every hint!

Comment: Most likely [UIPI](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vishalsi/2006/11/30/what-is-user-interface-privilege-isolation-uipi-on-vista/) is blocking the messages. In any case, you should be using `mouse_event()` or `SendInput()` instead of `PostMessage()`.

Comment: [`MK_LBUTTON` isn't a valid `wParam` for `WM_LBUTTONUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I don't think you need it for `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` either.

Comment: [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). The same principles apply here. You probably want to use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) instead. In case this really was rejected due to a UIPI boundary, then UI Automation is the only sane way to deal with this.

Comment: @computerfreaker Mhh thanks! Didn't look that up for WM_LBUTTONUP, because I thought it would be just the same as WM_LBUTTONDOWN, which I checked before...

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks so far aswell! I'm just confused, because I've seen some [other examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080777/what-sendmessage-to-use-to-send-keys-directly-to-another-window) where people were using PostMessage() or SendMessage() to send input. I didn't find SendInput or UI Automation in one of the pywin32 modules yet, but I will have a deeper look on it!

Comment: @IInspectable UI Automation looks promising, thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working now.. The above code is working well, the only thing I was not aware of was that I was getting my cursor position from `win32api.GetCursorPos()` in screen coordinates, but `win32gui.PostMessage()` needed the relative coordinates of the hWnd. Simply converting it with `ScreenToClient()` did the trick.

Comment: This answer saves my day! Appreaciate